# Android : Some textures not loading after resuming twice

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, ndk

This is an odd one.  When I press home and then restart my game I reload all my textures (checking glIsTexture on the id's first).  If I do this once, all textures load as expected, but if I do it **twice or more** one of my textures doesn't load (the texture is white).

I have checked glGetError and there are no errors (assuming GLES10.glGetError() is the correct way to do this)

Do I need to do any tidying up when home is pressed?  I currently call myGlView.onPause() and myGlView.onResume() when the onPause/Resume activity events are triggered.  I was under the impression that's all that's needed.  Is there anything else (perhaps non-openGL) that needs to be cleaned up?  Perhaps I'm hitting a limit of some kind

I am also using the NDK for some physics and rendering functions if that is relevant, but all resources are loaded using java.

Comment: Found the problem.  It was hidden in some legacy NDK code ported from the iOS version.  Previously I was loading and unloading textures in the native code.  In the destructor in question there was a glDeleteTextures call that was removing the texture.  I'm not sure why it didn't cause a problem on the first reload, but it now works.

Comment: Please add that as an answer and accept it so the question gets removed from the unanswered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was hidden in some legacy NDK code ported from the iOS version. Previously I was loading and unloading textures in the native code. In the destructor in question there was a glDeleteTextures call that was removing the texture. I'm not sure why it didn't cause a problem on the first reload, but it now works